# What are the restrictions in iOS background execution

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, background-process

This was a question asked to me in an interview, what are the restrictions on the application execution when it is working in background in iOS 5 and higher versions?

Comment: As Per Apple documentation iOS App only can perform task like play audio, monitor location or use VOIP client.

Comment: what are the possibilities for making server calls/requests

Comment: I do't think so as once your app entered in the background and is `frozen` by the Operating System no way for your app by it self to wake up and re-connect to the internet for make any kind of server calls.

Comment: So what you are trying to say if an app is in background you cannot even make a simple request.

Comment: Yes, And as in `iOS 7` Apple introduce some (Background fetch)[https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html] You can review this.

Answer (score 2):

See the below table for finding the background tasks that can be execute in background.

And see [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) for more details.

[image]